# Quadratic equation's roots satisfying the equation simultaneously

Tags: number-theory, roots, quadratics

Let $\alpha > \beta$  be the two distinct roots of some quadratic equation $ax² + bx + c = 0$ with $a , b,  c ≠  0$ , Prove that there exists unique $m$ & $n$ such that $\alpha\in[ m , n ]$

and $m$ , $n$ being integers satisfy the quadratic equation simultaneously i.e, $am² + bn + c = 0$ and $an² + bm + c = 0$ .

Another request- Please let me know the graphical interpretation of this question profile .

Comment: @Aqua they're simply integers ,

Comment: I don't understand your question.  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the only solutions to the equation, but you want to find extra solutions that are also integers?

Comment: @MatthewDaly actually one of the bigger roots belongs to a specified range , it's bounded and they're integers , m and n respectively.  They're ain't so called roots here ;)

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're combining your $m$ and $n$ in the second paragraph.

Comment: @MatthewDaly yes obviously , please let me know if there's any doubt regarding the question ,

Comment: I don't see how that is possible except $\alpha,\beta$ are integers.

Comment: $m, n$ must both be solutions of the quartic $$a^2x^4 + 2a^2cx^2 -bx + ac^2 + b^2c$$ If $a,b, c$ are integers themselves, then $m$ and $n$ are both divisors of $ac^2 + b^2c$, which would make them fairly quick to find for a specific case. When $a,b,c$ are not integer, it is hard to believe the quartic will always have 2 integer solutions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair x² + kx - k² = 0 ∀ $k\in N$ $\alpha\in [ 0 , k ]$

Comment: @Alphatrion - That doesn't even make sense. For each $k$ there are 2 values of $x$ for which it is true, but there is no $x$ for which it is true for all $k$. And I don't see how it is at all apropo to my comment.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It was for the question and not for your comment , which I'm unsure how you arrived at that result , I hope if there's some grave mistake in my question or concerns then please let me know sir .

Comment: I also don't see how it applies to your question. I got the equation by solving $am^2+bn+c = 0$ for $n$, then substituting that expression into $an^2 + bm + c = 0$ to get an equation in $m$ alone. And vice versa for $n$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sir if this is the case then pose a counter example which suits your argument and doesn't suits mine

Comment: What is your argument? I don't see one.

Comment: @PaulSinclair To the question, the answer is x² + kx - k² = 0 ∀ $k\in N$ $\alpha\in [ 0 , k ]$

Comment: ??? The question asks for a *proof* of the existence of $m, n$ with the properties described. Your "answer" doesn't even mention $m, n$ or the given polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$. And it certainly doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry sir , I do understand your concerns , It's just a glimpse that such quadratic equation with such mathematical system exists, to avoid unnecessary arguments and cross questions, next thing about proof , I'm hunting the best ones , and expecting the same from you